# How to leverage linq to sql better to optimize filtering and sorting data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

I have this code where I am trying to sort the top five most reported serotypes in a pathogen. Let's say there are 800+ serotypes that could possibly be reported. I start with an `ObjectQuery` that holds all the reports for that given pathogen. I now need to count the number of reports grouped by each serotype and pull back the top 5. This is how I have it written now:

```
Dictionary<string, int> unsorted = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//'serotypes' is an objectquery of 800+ serotypes
foreach (LookupSerotype serotype in serotypes)   
{
    var count = Reports.Count(r => r.serotypeId == serotype.serotypeId);
    unsorted.Add(serotype.serotypeName, count);
}

// convert to list in memory in order to sort the data
var sorted = unsorted.ToList();

sorted.Sort(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, int> first, KeyValuePair<string, int> next)
{
    return first.Value.CompareTo(next.Value);
});

// reverse because the largest were sorted to the bottom
sorted.Reverse();
```

Can I convert most (if not all) of this to more linq to sql in order to have these calculations done in query to the db? Or is there a quicker/better way entirely to pull this information?

**Specifically the first foreach loop at the beginning takes the longest and I could use help with**

Comment: Can we assume that there is a context having a property like `LookupSerotypes` (a `DbSet`). By the way, `ObjectQuery` isn't linq-to-sql, but entit framework.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right it's an entity framework object context. And I guess it would be going through EF not Linq-to-Sql for the query to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `serotypes` and `Reports` are EF `IQueryable`s, and assuming `serotype.serotypeId` is PK (unique), then you can use a single EF query based on [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) like this:

```
var query = 
    (from st in serotypes
     join r in Reports on st.serotypeId equals r.serotypeId into stReports
     order by st.serotypeName descending
     select new { st.serotypeName, reportCount = stReports.Count() }
    ).Take(5);

var result = query
    .AsEnumerable() // switch to LINQ to Objects context
    .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(e.serotypeName, e.reportCount))
    .ToList();
```

The only tricky part is the need to switch to LINQ to Objects context before the final projection, because EF does not support projecting (`select`) to class/struct w/o parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with LINQ, this should get you close:

```
var topFive = serotypes.GroupBy(s => s.serotypeName)
         .Select(s => new
         {
            SeroTypeName = s.serotypeName,
            Total = s.Count()
         }
         .OrderByDescending()
         .Take(5)
         .ToList();
```

Also, if you want to do some of the work on the server via a query, you can use this SQL:

```
Select Top 5 serotype.serotypeName, Count(*) as Total
  from serotype
group by serotype.serotypeName
order by Total Desc
```